# Add a div in another div by id?

Tags: jquery, html, css, append, selector

I have created a div:

```
<div id="mainbox"></div>
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum...</div>
```

Now I want to add the div 'div1' in the div 'mainbox':

```
$("#mainbox).append("#div1").
```

but it doesn't work as I want, but instead prints only text `#div1`

Comment: How are you triggering the addition?? By a button click perhaps?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Also, your html is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$("#mainbox").append($("#div1"))
```

With this, you are selecting #div1, the way you did it, you are only appending a string.

Please note that your div is hidden, so try also:

```
$("#div1").show();
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are checking the console in order to see if the div gets appended correctly? the div is hidden.

Comment: nice catch brother, even I was not able to figure out why it was not showing despite the fact that I was using correctly.

Comment: Sometimes you get stuck with something really simple. Happened to me many times :)

Answer (score 0):

please add the following line in your code in the script tag and it will resolve the issue:

```
 $("#mainbox").append($("#div1"))
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
                      {
                         $("#mainbox").append($("#div1"));
                      });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ruqaLhwn/1/)

```
<div id="mainbox"></div>
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">Lorem Ipsum...</div>

var $div1 = $("#div1");
$("#mainbox").append($div1.show())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div1").show();
var divtoadd = $("div1");   
$("#mainbox").html(divtoadd);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how you can do it

```
$('#mainbox').html($('#div1').html());
```

> Make sure you are using it in:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // your jquery statement
});
```